# How to write list values from a model to a C# file?

Tags: c#, json, api

I have a model to which the response from the API is written.
Here is what it looks like

```
    public class SparkPostTemplateModel
    {
        public List<SparkPostTemplateDetailModel> Results { get; set; }
    }
```

And SparkPostTemplateDetailModel:

```
    public class SparkPostTemplateDetailModel
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
    }
```

How can I save to JSON file each Id I got from an API?

This Is what I have got:

```
 private SparkPostTemplateModel EmailTemplates { get; set; } = new();

 public async Task SaveTemplate()
        {
            try
            {
                EmailTemplates = await SparkPostManager.GetTemplates();

                var test = EmailTemplates.Results.ToList();

                string fileName = "response.json";
                using FileStream createStream = File.Create(fileName);
                await JsonSerializer.SerializeAsync(createStream, EmailTemplates);
                await createStream.DisposeAsync();

 
                File.WriteAllText(@"C:\temp\Response.json", test.ToString());

                Console.WriteLine(File.ReadAllText(fileName));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
```

And what my program save to file:
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Test.API.Client.Infrastructure.Models.SparkPostTemplateDetailModel]

I want it to look like this:

Id1 
Id2 
Id3

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: What  you want to look like doesn't look like a json at all

Comment: So, you create a file "response.json" and serialize your EmailTemplates data as json into it. Great!. But wait... Then you use `File.WriteAllText` on what seems to be the very same file. Have you taken the time to look at File.WriteAllText's documentation, especially with regard to how it behaves when the file already exists? I am not sure at all what you are really trying to achieve. Do you want to get json, or do you just want a line-by-line output of your list content? Both?

Comment: Can you show what EmailTemplates  and test look like?

Comment: var test = EmailTemplates.Results.ToList() is a list. first retrieve data out of it using foreach, then assign the value to your model. only fetch the Id & assign to model

Answer (score 1):

Trying to transform a list to string wont tell you anything about it's contents. What if the list contains complex objects? what if the list contains more lists? That could get really confusing, so generic list only show you the most basic information about them when transforming them to strings.

Not sure why you are calling JsonSerializer.SerializeAsync, your wanted result isn't really a valid json file, more like a plain text file.

Your code is almost there, you just need to take each element in your list and append it to your file:

```
private SparkPostTemplateModel EmailTemplates { get; set; } = new();

public async Task SaveTemplate()
{
  try
  {
    EmailTemplates = await SparkPostManager.GetTemplates();

    var test = EmailTemplates.Results.ToList();

    await using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText(fileName))

    //loop through the list elements and append lines
    foreach (var template in test)
    {
         w.WriteLine(template.Id);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(File.ReadAllText(fileName));
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   throw;
}
```

This should work

**Edit - File per loop**

```
private SparkPostTemplateModel EmailTemplates { get; set; } = new();

public async Task SaveTemplate()
{
  try
  {
    EmailTemplates = await SparkPostManager.GetTemplates();

    var test = EmailTemplates.Results.ToList();

    //AppendText will create a new file, if the file doesn't exist already
    
    //insead of a foreach loop, do a regular for loop, so we can track the index of our elements
    for (int i = 0; i < test.Count; i++)
    {
         //use the index to name the file (add plus one, so the numeration starts with the number one)
         await using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText($"file{i + 1}.txt"))

         //retrieve the object from the list using our index
         w.WriteLine(test[i].Id);
    }

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   throw;
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you! It works but how can I create new file after every loop?
I mean. Id1 = first file, Id2 = second file.

Can you edit your answer?
Thank you so much!

Comment: Not sure why you want that but there you go, hope it helps!

Comment: Hello. I mean something like that:
I have got response with Id's.
Every file I want to name like Id => and place inside id value.

For example
Id = "test" => make file test.json (inside text ->test)
Id = "hello" => male file hello.json (inside text -> hello)

etc.

I very much appreciate!!!

Comment: var data = EmailTemplates.Results.ToList();
                var fileName = "response.json";

                await using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText(fileName))
                {
                    foreach (var template in data)
                    {
                        //File.AppendText(template.Id);
                        File.AppendText($"{template.Id}.json");
                        w.WriteLine(template.Id);
                    }
                }

Right now I have this code. It makes me files but without any content

Comment: the edit in my response should help you with whant you want, and for the problem with the empty files, I will try that code later as I can't right now. Will update my answer then.

Comment: I have almost an solution. My last problem is. Can I add dynamic path to AppendText?
I mean File.AppendText($"C:\test\{template.Id}.json"))

To create files in specific folder?

Everything else works

Comment: Yes, the code you just posted should work.

Comment: @TheRobertos This is absurd, Why would you want to save each id in a separate file and that too a `json` file? A json file should have a proper JSON while just saving an Id would not be a proper `json`.